# Restart service if blocks dont increase over 20s (bash scipt)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I run a blockchain node from BSC (Binance smart chain) and I'd like to implement a script that periodically (30s) check if blocks are increasing and if not it would then restart the systemd service.

That's what I've started:

```
#!/bin/bash 

bsc_height=$(curl http://localhost:8545 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","id": 0,"method": "eth_blockNumber"}' | awk -F ":" '{ print $4}' | sed 's|["{},]||g')
bsc_height_decimal=$(echo $((bsc_height)))
```

With that I'm able to get the current block's high through the variable `bsc_height_decimal`, let's say the value of it is currently `13083806`. How would a bash loop that checks it every 30s and perform `systemctl restart bsc` if the count doesn't increase over this period of time look like?

My idea is to then run this script as a systemd service, or maybe crontab? I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it, what you guys think?

Comment: It is never necessary (and probably never useful) to pipe `awk` output into `sed`.

Comment: FYI systemd service makes exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r WAIT_SEC='30'

bsc_height_decimal=
bsc_height_decimal_old=

while true; do
        bsc_height=$(curl http://localhost:8545 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","id": 0,"method": "eth_blockNumber"}' | awk -F ":" '{ print $4}' | sed 's|["{},]||g')
        bsc_height_decimal=$(echo $((bsc_height)))
        if [ -n "$bsc_height_decimal_old" ] && [ "$bsc_height_decimal_old" -eq "$bsc_height_decimal" ]; then
                systemctl restart bsc
        fi
        bsc_height_decimal_old="$bsc_height_decimal"
        sleep "$WAIT_SEC"
done
```

And

```
awk -F ":" '{ print $4}' | sed 's|["{},]||g'
```

can be replaced by

```
awk -F ":" '{ output=$4; gsub("[\"{},]","",output); print output;}'
```

Comment: The first arg to gsub() is a regexp, not a string. If you use regexp instead of string delimiters then you won't need to escape the double quote - `gsub(/["{},]/,"",output)`. It doesn't hurt but you don't actually need the variable either, `gsub(/["{},]/,"",$4); print $4`

Comment: thank you very much guys

Comment: @Daniel If you are satisfied with this answer then you should accept it so that your question does not look unanswered any more.